# Setuptools Installed script cannot find text file

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools

I am trying to make a package using setuptools. The package is getting installed correctly, I can see the log copying the .txt file. But when the script tries to open it, it give "no such file or directory" error.

Text file name is "stopwords.txt"

```
Hierarichy:
   wcounter
        |
        --setup.py
        --MANIFEST.in
        --README.md
        --wcounter
             |
             --module1.py
             --module2.py
             --stopwords.txt
```

Setup.py

```html
from setuptools import setup, find_packages 
<br>
<br>
setup( name = "wcounter",<br> 
        version = "1.0",<br> 
        packages = find_packages(),<br> 
        package_data = {"": ["stopwords.txt"]},<br> 
        include_package_data = True, <br>
        zip_safe = True, <br>
        entry_points = {'console_scripts' : ['wcount = wcounter.wcounter:main'],},<br>
)
```

I am trying to access the file by using file IO.
ex. f = open("stopwords.txt","r)

Answer (score 0):

In python, when using a relative path to open a file -- `open("stopwords.txt", "r")` -- the path will be relative to the current working directory, not the python file that the file is being opened from.

For instance, consider the following script:

```
C:\temp> python C:\path\to\myscript.py
```

If `myscript.py` attempts to `open('stopwords.txt')`, it will be looking in `C:\temp\stopwords.txt`, not `C:\path\to\stopwords.txt`.

You need to refer explicitly to the full path of `stopwords.txt`.  You can do this by using the magic `__file__` attribute.

For example, if you're trying to open the file from `module1.py` in your example, you would do

```
import os
fp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'stopwords.txt')
open(fp, 'r')
```

`os.path.abspath` ensures it's a full path (in certain circumstances, `__file__` will be a relative path).

`os.path.dirname` gets the directory portion of the module name -- `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wcounter`.

`os.path.join` joins the directory and the filename together to make a full absolute path.